# SFDX cli throwing eslint error

Tags: salesforcedx, vs-code

Does anyone have any ideas on how to fix this? It just randomly started happening when using vscode:

[image]

This is how my current sfdx-project.json file looks like:

[image]

```
{
  "packageDirectories": [
    {
      "path": "force-app",
      "default": true,
      "dependencies": [ 
        {
           "package": "PACKAGENAME@1.1.0.4"
        }
     ]
    }
  ],
  "namespace": "",
  "sfdcLoginUrl": "https://login.salesforce.com",
  "sourceApiVersion": "45.0",
  "packageAliases": {
      "PACKAGNAME@1.1.0.4": "VERSIONID"
  }

}
```

Comment: could you share your sfdx-project.json file ?

Comment: @MohithShrivastava done!

Comment: @scarecrow can you provide a text version of the file as well? Easy to copy paste if someone wants to replicate.

Comment: @JayantDas Done

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like in your sfdx-project.json file the **package** and **VersionNumber** are both missing .

**package** - This is the name identifier for the package .

**VersionNumber** - This is required by the CLI to know what to generate next when CLI commands for version generate is executed .

Check the updated specification [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev2gp_config_file.htm). ESlint rules have been updated as well I believe in the CLI causing the issues.

The below seems to be working for me

```
 {
"packageDirectories": [{
    "path": "force-app",
    "default": true,
    "package": "PACKAGNAME",
    "versionNumber": "1.1.0.NEXT",
    "dependencies": [{
        "package": "PACKAGENAME@1.1.0.4"
    }]
}],
"namespace": "",
"sfdcLoginUrl": "https://login.salesforce.com",
"sourceApiVersion": "45.0",
"packageAliases": {
    "PACKAGNAME@1.1.0.4": "VERSIONID"
 }

}
```

Comment: So I now have to generate a package for a non ready app? thats a bummer

Comment: Not generate package .Sorry if I am unclear you just have to choose the name for it .Usually it is not needed when you have no package to begin with  but when you generate one the cli auto adds this info .Since you already had this that's why eslint is throwing an error .All you need is to assign some name .

Comment: +1. I did come through the docs you mentioned but did not realize that those attributes are marked as required in case of packaging.

Comment: Interesting, I don't even have a package version created for the this app so I guess I will go and generate one. Very interesting change that it is now required guess I shouldnt have restarted vscode!

Comment: You don't have to create one .Just say 0.0.1.NEXT